# How can I use a variable in a jQuery attribute selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selectbox with several options - each of these option values correspond to a "value" attribute on some images below. The functionality I want is when selectbox value is changed the img with the corresponding value is highlighted with a red border. Here is the code:

```
function assignValue() {
  selectboxvalue = $('#Box_style').val() ;
  $('.tabContent img[value="+selectboxvalue+"]').css({border: '1px solid #c10000'});
}

$('#Box_style').change(assignValue);
```

Looking around at the jquery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector), apparently this should work...

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: I think your problem is simply that you mixed up `'` and `"`.

Comment: @kinsey This is a failure to understand basic string operations, not the functionality of jQuery. It would be a good idea for you to try to understand strings and concatenation. The actually What and Why of the problem, not the How. If you are programming in a text editor an IDE with syntax highlighting (and understanding why things highlight the way they do) would help a bunch

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Prior to jQuery 1.7**

The following will work:

```
$('.tabContent img[value='+selectboxvalue+']').css({border: '1px solid #c10000'});
```

**jQuery 1.7 and later**

In 1.7 jQuery changed the syntax to require the `attributes` to have quotation around the value:

```
$('.tabContent img[value="'+selectboxvalue+'"]').css({border: '1px solid #c10000'});
```

Answer (score 7):

Quotes are messed up:

```
  $('.tabContent img[value="'+selectboxvalue+'"]').css({border: '1px solid #c10000'});
```

Answer (score 1):

To the above, it no longer works as mentioned above (, though it might also be only my code). The single quotation messes up the code. The following code works

**As of jQuery 3.2.1 and later**

```
$("#clickmap a[gruppe="+gruppeId+"]").children("path").addClass('lastClicked');
```