# JQuery: selecting element with specific data-attribute's value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given n html elements with data attributes such :

```
<div class="tpl" data-points="2"></div>
<div class="tpl" data-points="5"></div>
<div class="tpl" data-points="10"></div>
<div class="tpl" data-points="5"></div>
```

Given a JS variable such as :

```
foo=10;
```

**How to select the element with `data-points==foo;` ?** (which currently is `10` but may change)

**What is the suitable selector ?**

Comment: Who reopened this and why? It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6131119/218196, or the ones I mention below.

Comment: The question contains two parts: [Selecting an element by attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute) and [using a variable in a selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5891840/218196).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.tpl[data-points=' + foo + ']')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vqX2D/)**