# Add class to href if it links to current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to make a javascript function to check if a link on the page links to the same page, and if so, add a class to it.

What I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentPage = location.pathname;
  if $("a[href*=currentPage]") {
  $("a").addClass( "active" );
  }
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery attribute selector variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131119/jquery-attribute-selector-variable)

Comment: See the syntax in that question for how to use a variable in an attribute selector.

Comment: add `()` => `if ($("a[href*=currentPage]")) {...}`

Comment: There are a couple of basic errors in this code, and a variable should not be included in a string like that. Maybe you would benefit from following some beginners tutorials as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure JavaScript (IE 9 and above)

```
var currentPage = location.href;
var allA = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
for(var i = 0, len = allA.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(allA[i].href == currentPage) {
         allA[i].className = "active";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var currentPage = location.pathname;
$('a').each(function() {
    var currentHref = $(this).attr('href');
    if(currentHref == currentPage) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
})
```

Should do the trick. Pay attention to the fact that some links might include the domain.

Comment: Most links will be relative links, but not necessarily, You may need to remove the website root(s) before comparing to be safe.

Comment: How would you remove the website roots?

Comment: Unable to get this solution to function, it doesn't add a class to any link to the current page.