# Add class to an element if on same url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the following bit of code to work, but I seem to be missing something

```js
var dom = document.URL;
$("a[href=dom]").addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="http://example.com">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        Home
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://example.com/about">
        <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
        About
    </a>
</li>
```

What's supposed to happen is when at `http://example.com` the class `active` will be added to the first `a` element, if at `http://example.com/about` then the second `a` will get the class.

I used javascript's `alert` to make sure I was getting the right URL, and it is as it shows in `href`, however what I have above doesn't work. I have tried the Javascript responses given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043180/add-class-to-href-if-it-links-to-current-page) but they don't work either.

Comment: You just need to concatenate the variable: `$('a[href="' + dom + '"]').addClass("active");`

Comment: you need to use `window.location.href ` instead, and remove the class from all of those anchors prior to setting the class, otherwise they'll all have it

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Seemed like a well put together question to me especially from a newer stack overflow member.

Comment: Thanks Rory, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href=dom]").addClass("active");
```

should be

```
$("a[href=" + dom + "]").addClass("active");
```

You're mixing in a variable with a string. Also, I would recommend just adding a class to the body and targeting the current page like that. It's much more reusable.