# JQuery: How to find an input with a value that is defined in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a list of HTML radio buttons each with their own value (say 1 - 10)

I also have a hidden field with a set value (say 5)

I want to find the input that has the value of the hiddenfield

```
$('.block').each(function (index) {
    var hiddenVal = $('.myHiddenField').val();
    var inputWithHiddenVal = $(this).find('li input[value="5"]')
});
```

I want the input[value="5"] to use the hiddenVal variable

e.g.

```
$(this).find('li input[value="hiddenVal"]')
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131119/jquery-attribute-selector-variable

Comment: you can mix string and variables using `+`, you just need to close the string with quotes `"` or `'` and use the other one inside the string like this:

`$(this).find('li input[value="'+hiddenVal +'"]')`

or you can escape the quotes like this:

`$(this).find("li input[value=\""+hiddenVal +"\"]")`

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the value from the variable using `+`, the concatenate operator.

```
$('.block').each(function (index) {
    var hiddenVal = $('.myHiddenField').val();
    var inputWithHiddenVal = $(this).find('li input[value="'+hiddenVal +'"]')
});
```